# Join Table B and get values of different columns depending on values in a specific column from Table A

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to join two tables via ID. The first table has all the IDs and a column with the column names from the other table. I did this with a case statement and if worked but I have like 50 differnet column names and more to come so I don't want to use the case statement. What can I do instead? I'm using Snowflake, this is what I have:

Table A:

[tableA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1skr.png)

Table B:

[tableB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWHzJ.png)

**create table statements:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
    TABLE_A
    (id          INTEGER,
     column_name VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO
    test.TABLE_A
    (id,column_name)
    VALUES
    (1,'column_1'),
    (1,'column_2'),
    (2,'column_2');

---------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
    TABLE_B
    (id       INTEGER,
     column_1 VARCHAR,
     column_2 VARCHAR); 

INSERT INTO
    TABLE_B
    (id,column_1,column_2)
    VALUES
    (1,'value_1_1','value_1_2'),
    (2,'value_2_1','value_2_2');
```

This is what I did but as I said this is bad for maintainance:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.COLUMN_NAME,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.column_name = 'column_1'
        THEN b.column_1
        WHEN a.column_name = 'column_2'
        THEN b.column_2
        ELSE ''
    END AS result
FROM
    TABLE_A a
JOIN 
    TABLE_B b
ON 
    a.id = b.id
```

This gives me the following result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKFUU.png)

How can I get this result without using the case statement or having to type the strings into any condition?

Comment: This seems to be a very odd table design. Can you explain what requirements you have that led you to need to design and populate these tables in this way? To respond to your specific question, there is no way of dynamically selecting columns in a pure SQL statement, you’d have to do this in some sort of stored proc which may not produce data in a structure that you can easily use

Comment: NickW can you post your comment as an answer? so people can see that the question is answered.